# Incorrect syntax near ')'. IN PROCEDURE

Tags: sql-server

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'spGetEmployeeListWithOutputVariable')
BEGIN
        EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEmployeeListWithOutputVariable
        @NoOfRecord INT OUTPUT
        AS
        BEGIN
        SELECT @NoOfRecord = COUNT(EmployeeID)
        FROM EmployeeData
        SELECT 
            employee.EmployeeId,
            employee.EmployeeName,
            employee.ContactNumber,
            STUFF((SELECT ',' + hobby.Name FROM Hobbies AS hobby    
                            JOIN dbo.MapHobbiesData AS MapEmpHob 
                                ON MapEmpHob.HobbiesId=hobby.HobbiesId     
                            WHERE MapEmpHob.EmployeeId=employee.EmployeeId
                            FOR XML PATH(''))
                ,1,1,'')  Hobbies,
                NoOfEmpRecords = @NoOfRecord
        FROM EmployeeData AS employee
        END')
END
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the static query?

Comment: I have tried and it is executed.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani How can that possibly be true? The SQL above has a syntax error.

Comment: Not syntax error i got only inncorrect syntax error ')' this only

Comment: For me its not working @ Chetan Sanghani

Answer (score 5):

Your SQL is incorrect due to the single quotes inside the SQL string. You need to escape these. For example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'spGetEmployeeListWithOutputVariable')
BEGIN
        EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEmployeeListWithOutputVariable
        @NoOfRecord INT OUTPUT
        AS
        BEGIN
        SELECT @NoOfRecord = COUNT(EmployeeID)
        FROM EmployeeData
        SELECT 
            employee.EmployeeId,
            employee.EmployeeName,
            employee.ContactNumber,
            STUFF((SELECT '','' + hobby.Name FROM Hobbies AS hobby    
                            JOIN dbo.MapHobbiesData AS MapEmpHob 
                                ON MapEmpHob.HobbiesId=hobby.HobbiesId     
                            WHERE MapEmpHob.EmployeeId=employee.EmployeeId
                            FOR XML PATH(''''))
                ,1,1,'''')  Hobbies,
                NoOfEmpRecords = @NoOfRecord
        FROM EmployeeData AS employee
        END')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

replace single inverted comma (') with double inverted comma ('')

```
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEmployeeListWithOutputVariable
        @NoOfRecord INT OUTPUT
        AS
        BEGIN
        SELECT @NoOfRecord = COUNT(EmployeeID)
        FROM EmployeeData
        SELECT 
            employee.EmployeeId,
            employee.EmployeeName,
            employee.ContactNumber,
            STUFF((SELECT '','' + hobby.Name FROM Hobbies AS hobby    
                            JOIN dbo.MapHobbiesData AS MapEmpHob 
                                ON MapEmpHob.HobbiesId=hobby.HobbiesId     
                            WHERE MapEmpHob.EmployeeId=employee.EmployeeId
                            FOR XML PATH(''''))
                ,1,1,'''')  Hobbies,
                NoOfEmpRecords = @NoOfRecord
        FROM EmployeeData AS employee
        END')
```